# Traverse directory structure in Javascript with callback for each hit

Tags: javascript, callback, directory, lazy-evaluation

There are a number of options for traversing a directory tree in Javascript (`node-dir`, `fs.readdir`, ...) and most supports asynchronous execution with a callback when finished.

But is there a framework that supports callbacks on each found file? I want to build a loader for audio files that incrementally adds the files as they are found.

Plain Javascript (or Typescript) solutions are also accepted.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. You don't need to call your callback "on hit". You can traverse the directory, building a list of paths to files found. _Then_, loop through that list and call your function for each path. You can wrap all this in an API which accepts a root directory and a callback. Recursive paths listing is usually found in most `fs` wrapper modules so you're halfway there.

Comment: What is the environment for _"lazy loader for audio files"_? Client-side? Are you trying to create a playlist?

Comment: @guest271314 node.js application. Smart playlists with special features.

Comment: What do you mean by "lazy loader"? You can flatten the directory to an array of values and iterate the array, perform a "callback" for each element of the array.

Comment: @guest271314 "lazy loading" in the same way as reactive programming, populating and updating information as new files "are found". (Not stricly lazy, I know...)

Comment: What do you mean by "are found"? Is the directory populated dynamically? Or are you traversing a static directory of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that traversing the structure was costly, and wanted to do the work for each file as it was found by the traversal, instead of collecting a list first. But experiments show that this is not the case, traversal is in fact very cheap compared to just opening a file, let alone parsing content. So I'll go with the suggestion from @Joseph and just use one of the options listed and call the function for each file.

I'll make this incremental by doing this asynchronously and update the UI reactively.

Thanks, for straightening out my thinking.